# Using SAML/OpenID Connect to implement SSO for two websites. How to authenticate Swing client?

Tags: single-sign-on, native, saml, openid-connect

I am trying to implement SSO for two websites and have currently looked into `SAML` and `OpenID Connect`. But I need to authenticate a Swing based desktop client using the same credentials.

I have read about the implicit flow of OpenID Connect but it still needs to open a browser it seems.

SAML Enhanced Client or Proxy profile which seems to solve this kind of problem seems to not be implemented by most idps I have tried out. (Only Shibboleth supports it and the documentation for Shibboleth is not that good).

- What kind of solution works for this problem?
- Are there any other SSO mechanisms that support both native and web
  apps?
- Are there workarounds for OpenID Connect/SAML for this kind of
  problem?
- Would it be a good idea to just expose a REST API that authenticates
  the Swing client using the same credentials as the SSO IdP?

Comment: Design a simple custom token to authenticate: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Comment: The desktop app you are talking about is managed by the same company as the identity provider right ? Another way of saying this : do you have control over both the codebase of the identity provider AND desktop app ?

Comment: @MichaelakoTecourt yes

Answer (score 2):

OpenID Connect tries to solve the problem of sharing user authentication between two parties : the identity provider (OP) and a client.

This is not clearly stated in the OIDC docs, but based on my experience **OIDC doesn't try to solve how you authenticate your own users accross different platforms** (web, mobile/desktop).

That's one of the very few valid use cases for the OAuth 2.0 "[Resource Owner Password Credentials grant](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27.html#grant-password)", where the client [exchanges](https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security/) the user credentials for a token.

Here you are inside your own system, your mobile/desktop application cannot be considered a third party, it only provides a trusted way for the user to send you its credentials.
You can make sure the app does not store them since you have control over the codebase.

**EDIT :** The mobile app instances can share (unless you manage to dynamically assign client IDs) a [client ID/secret that cannot be kept confidential](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27.html#rfc.section.2.1). It makes up a [really thin](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64091/oauth2-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant) client authentication layer, trying to make sure that the requests do come from your mobile/desktop application :

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic ${BASE64_ENCODED_CLIENTID_CLIENTSECRET}
  grant_type=password&
  username=${USERNAME}&
  password=${PASSWORD}
```

Some people dislike that it specifies *how* to authenticate a user, and some companies may have additional credentials than username+password, for example when using 2-factor authentication. Also, some people used  the ROPC grant wrong, as it is only valid inside an organization, allowing a client to request your own user credentials is killing the point of having an SSO/authorization protocol.

[OIDC is still OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047047/does-openid-connect-support-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/27714346#comment51346303_27714346), which means you are free to implement your own "user credentials" flow to obtain an access token + ID Token from your desktop/mobile app. It's outside the scope of OIDC though.

BTW, [SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) was created at a time when mobile apps were not really in the picture :

> SAML 2.0 was ratified as an OASIS Standard in March 2005