# What is the purpose of Resource Owner Password Credential Grant Type in OAuth 2.0?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

Based on the answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135792/oauth-2-0-and-session-management/39152888#39152888)

Ok, OAuth 2.0 is an authorization protocol but when you use ROPC (Resource Owner Password Credential) Grant Type, the way I understand it, you mean to authenticate and authorize isn't it?

Is OpenID still applicable in ROPC? still a little bit confuse with OAuth 2.0 ROPC and OpenID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type does authenticate users but is a non-typical OAuth 2.0 grant type that is only meant for migration purposes, as the spec says:

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is often used for
>   legacy or migration reasons.  It reduces the overall risk of storing
>   usernames and passwords by the client but does not eliminate the need 
>   to expose highly privileged credentials to the client.
>
> This grant type carries a higher risk than other grant types
>   because    it maintains the password anti-pattern this protocol seeks
>   to avoid.

The Resource Owner Password Credentials grant is not prohibited with OpenID Connect (even though the OpenID Connect spec does not clearly define it beyond OAuth 2.0) but defeats the primary purpose of a federated SSO protocol that OpenID Connect is supposed to be. That is because it locks RPs in to a single authentication method whereby the user credentials are disclosed to the RP. You mileage wrt. to support across Providers may vary.

See also: [Does OpenID Connect support the Resource Owner Password Credentials grant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047047/does-openid-connect-support-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant)

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the power of resource owner password credentials(ROPC) is utilized properly when we use the refresh token.

Consider a mobile app where user needs to log in. Once logged in and request a token using your clientId, secret, userid and password, normally you get an access token and a refresh token. Access token is normally valid for less time(say 1 hour) and refresh token is valid for a longer time(say 24 hours). ClientId and Secret is stored in the App. UserId and Password is owned by user and never stored anywhere.

When the user tries to access the app after 1 hour, his access token is expired which means in normal scenario, he needs to log in again. 
But we can avoid this tedious task of entering his userId and password again by getting a new access token(and new refresh token) by exchanging the refresh token along with the clientId and Secret(no userId and password needed). The new access token will have all the same features of the previous access token. This means as long as user is active atleast 24 hours ago, he doesn't have to log in again. After 24 hours of idle time, both refresh token and access token expires and the log in is required to get a new access token.