# OpenID Connect Authentication Flow (using KeyCloak) in a Mobile App + REST Backend

Tags: rest, authentication, mobile, oauth, openid-connect

I'd like to secure the REST-backend of our mobile app using [OpenID Connect](https://connect2id.com/learn/openid-connect). In short, users of the app should authenticate themselves (username/password) before fetching sensitive data over the REST backend (multiple services).

After initial authentication they should receive an id/access token that they then can use for service-communication for the remainder of their app session. It is very important that i get this ID token since it contains info that is needed by the backend.

As an Identity Provide for implementing this scenario I'd like to use [KeyCloak](http://keycloak.org). However, I am unsure about the best auth flow to implement. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047047/does-openid-connect-support-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/24050911#24050911) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047047/does-openid-connect-support-the-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/24050911#24050911) stackoverflow posts but I am still unsure if my desired solution is valid/safe/acceptable.

From what i've read about openID Connect the recommended openID Connect auth flow is the "3-legged **authorization code flow**" which involves:

1. redirecting the user to the login page of the Identity Provider (in my case KeyCloak) for authentication (for example login form).
2. after successfull authentication the IP then redirects the user back to the app along with an auth code passed as request parameter.
3. the app can then fetch the id/acccess tokens from the IP by passing this authentication code to the "standardized" token endpoint.

This all sounds very well for a browser-based web app, but in our app we would like to avoid the external login page and instead have a "local" in-app login page so to not break the user exprience too much. Also, our app has a feature that keeps you "logged in". In this case the user logs in only once and all tokens are then fetched in the background by the app when it is started.

So, based on our requirements I found [this](http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/10/getting-started-with-keycloak-securing.html) blog post, that uses a 2-legged  **Resource Owner Credentials flow** approach that allows the app to authenticate itself AND collect the tokens in ONE request, without the need for navigating to the keycloak login page.

I tested this and this solution seems to provide exactly the functionality we need. Also, in our case the app and KeyCloak (=Self-Issued OpenID Provider) are solely used internally and belong to the same legal entity.

**Is it, in our use-case, allowed to use the 2-legged approach, and if not, why not? Does this approach impose some security risks that the 3-legged approach does not?**

I really hope to hear from you guys!

**Update 16-10-2018:** Wow guys, I found a very interesting tutorial-presentation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0) from Nate Barbettini that covers oauth, openid connect and the type of authentication flows in very clear terms but also very in-depth. I'd recommend everybody to view this preentation before venturing further in the complex world of authorization/authentication using ouath/openid connect.

Regards,

Kim
The Netherlands

Comment: did you get this to work ?

Comment: Can you provide new link for the sample project?
https://github.com/stianst/keycloak-blog-gs is not found

Comment: @kim  I have a same situation where i have to implement this flow in mobile app using keycloak. Please let me know if you get this to work? Thanks in advance.......

Comment: @NullPointer : Yes i got it to work by following the mentioned blog in my post. However, I only secured my REST services this way an tested this over CURL. To obtain tokens from your mobile app you need to look for a keycloak-client library for your platform (for cordava f.e.: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/master/examples/cordova)

Comment: @kim for Device Management , Where Keycloak store Device_id and Device_model ,How ? is it support in Keycloak?

Comment: @Wecherowski Uh..., what great blog post do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `Resource Owner Credentials` flow should be avoided unless really needed AND the client app and environment are under your own full control. You may have full control over the app but you cannot control the phone OS (security updates, ...)

This [blog post](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/fact-sheet-the-dangers-of-using-the-password-grant-type-with-mobile-applications) goes over the various problems. I do not fully agree with all the points mentioned in that post but I quote a few relevant ones:

- Flies in the face of the OAuth best practice guidelines (RFC8252)
- Public client applications cannot keep a secret and therefore cannot authenticate themselves
- Significantly increases the attack surface on user credentials (if the client is compromised, so is the user's entire account)

Also here is an excerpt from O'Reilly book [Getting Started with OAuth 2.0 by Ruan Boyd](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781449317843/ch04.html):

> When Should the Resource Owner Password Flow Be Used? 
>   Because the resource owner’s password is exposed to the application, this flow
>   should be used sparingly. It is recommended only for first-party
>   “official” applications released by the API provider, and not opened
>   up to wider third-party developer communities.
>
> If a user is asked to type their password into “official”
>   applications, they may become accustomed to doing so and become
>   vulnerable to phishing attempts by other apps. In order to mitigate
>   this concern, developers and IT administrators should clearly educate
>   their users how they should determine which apps are “official” and
>   which are not.

Answer (score -1):

the following link save my time a lot.
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/01/29/api-login-and-jwt-token-generation-using-keycloak#set_up_a_client

the most important thing in my oppinion is

> Fill in all of the mandatory fields in the client form. Pay attention,
> especially, to Direct Grant Flow (shown in Figure 6) and set its value
> to direct grant. Also, change Access Type to confidential.

and also the URL where we have to send our credential to be validated.

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/whatever-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=clientid-03' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=ec78c6bb-8339-4bed-9b1b-e973d27107dc' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
--data-urlencode 'username=emuhamma' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1'
```